# Validar en php 2 horas en formato HH:MM

Tags: php

Tengo un ejercicio de validaciones de horas con `php`.

- Las horas pasadas por parámetros deben ser de 5 caracteres de longitud
- El formato de la hora debe ser "HH:MM"
- Los caracteres correspondientes a las horas y minutos deben ser numéricos
- Las horas deben estar entre 0 y 23
- Los minutos deben estar entre 0 y 59

He pensado que la mejor manera es utilizar `DateTime()` al trabajar con horas. Pero no consigo aclararme con las conversiones y me da error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: DateTime - DateTime in C:\xampp\htdocs\Validarcatastrofe\reeditado.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Validarcatastrofe\reeditado.php(35): validarHoras('15:00', '11:00') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Validarcatastrofe\reeditado.php on line 24**

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Prueba ejercicio</h1>

    <?php 
   

    function validarHoras($hora1, $hora2){

    try{
       $horaRestada;
       $horaInicial= new DateTime($hora1);
       $horaInicialFormateada=$horaInicial->format('H:i');
       $horaFinal= new DateTime($hora2);
       $horaFinalFormateada=$horaFinal->format('H:i');


       if($horaInicialFormateada==$hora1){
         if($horaFinalFormateada==$hora2){
            $horaRestada=$horaInicial->diff($horaFinal);
            $horaRestada=$horaRestada->format('%H:%I') ;
            echo "<h1>LA HORA RESTADA ES ".$horaRestada."</h1>";

         }
         
       }
       
     }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Formato incorrecto";
    }

   }

     validarHoras('23:00', "10:00");
   ?>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no puedes hacer restas directas con objetos de tipo DateTime en ese lugar deberias utilizar diff(), te dejare un ejemplo como respuesta y lo adaptas a tu necesidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes conocer es que `DateTime` retorna un objeto y ul objeto no se puede restar de otro objeto como si se tratara de numeros, por ende esta linea de codigo te arroja error:

```php
$horaRestada=$horaInicial-$horaFinal;
```

para calcular la diferencia de tiempo entre 2 objeto de tipo `DateTime` debes implementar el metodo [`diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) del objeto:

*Ejemplo:*

```php
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("2021-01-01");
$date2 = new DateTime("2022-06-30");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

echo $interval->format("%y años, %m meses, %d dias");
```

output:

> 1 años, 5 meses, 29 dias

Ahora tiene una situacion particular ya que buscar calcular las horas:

*Ejemplo:*

```php
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("12:35");
$date2 = new DateTime("15:55");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

echo $interval->format("%H:%I");
```

output:

> 03:20

Este ultimo ejemplo indica las horas y minutos de trabajo calculadas segun la hora de entrada y salida, pero no es completa, explico a continuacion por que.

---

Ahora si quieres implementar una Clase en tu sistema PHP que se encargue del calculo bastaria con algo asi:

```php
class HourManager
{
    static public function calcWorkHours($initial,$end)
    {
        try{
            $date1 = new DateTime($initial);
            $date2 = new DateTime($end);
            $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
            return $interval->format("%H:%I");
        }catch (Exception $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

echo HourManager::calcWorkHours("12:35","15:55");
```

output:

> 03:20

hasta este punto hemos realizado el calculo; pero no hemos agregados los controles que agregaste; ahora agregando esos controles quedaria asi:

```php
<?php
class HourManager
{
    static public function calcWorkHours($initial,$end)
    {
        try{
            $pattern = "/^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/";
            if(strlen($initial) != 5 || strlen($end) != 5 || !preg_match($pattern, $initial) || !preg_match($pattern, $end)){
                throw new Exception("Los pamaretros de hora deben tener exactamente 5 caracteres con el siguiente formato HH:MM entre 00:00 a 23:59");
            }
        
            $date1 = new DateTime($initial);
            $date2 = new DateTime($end);
            $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
            return $interval->format("%H:%I");
        }catch (Exception $ex){
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

echo HourManager::calcWorkHours("12:35","15:55");
```

output:

> 03:20

**Nota importante:** Si tu captura de datos no es una fecha completa corres el riesgo de perder horas, esto es importante cuando tienes turnos rotativos y algun empleado dobla o triplica turnos laborales.

Ejemplo con perdida de horas:

```php
echo HourMAnager::calcWorkHours("2022-02-03 12:35","2022-02-04 15:55");
```

output Errado:

> 03:20

output esperado:

> 27:20

esto ocurre por que no se evaluan los dias; para solventar el escenarios debemos incluir tambien el dia trabajado:

```php
<?php

class HourManager
{
    static public function calcWorkHours($initial, $end)
    {
        try {
            $date1 = new DateTime($initial);
            $date2 = new DateTime($end);
            $interval = $date2->diff($date1);
            $totalMinutes = ($interval->days * 1440) + ($interval->h * 60) + $interval->i;
            $hours = (int) ($totalMinutes / 60);
            $minutes = $totalMinutes % 60;
            return sprintf("%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

echo HourManager::calcWorkHours("2022-02-03 12:35","2022-02-04 15:55");
```

output Correcto:

> 27:20

Comment: Bien, me funciona. Pero una salvedad. Yo le quiero pasar a la funcion validarHora 2 argumentos que son validarHora(23:00, 11:00) por ejemplo. En tu ejemplo la funcion calcWorkHours(23:00, 11:00). No se por que si le inserto 24:00 sigue funcionando porque tengo entendido que al usar format('%H:%i') el rango es de 00 a 23 para horas y de 00 a 59 para minutos. La idea es que necesito validar que no están fuera de ese rango las horas introducidas como argumento.

Comment: Simplemente necesito validar que el formato introducido es HH:mm. ¿tal vez una expresion regular?

Comment: ya te lo agrego pero hago la salvedad de que  ... datetime funciona desde 00:00:00 hasta 23:59:59 el calculo arrojada la diferencia de tiempo: si colocas 24:00 deberia ser un error esa hora no existe ...

Comment: @JoseL. ya esta listo usando `preg_match`

Comment: ten en cuanta que en php esto (23:00, 11:00) no te va a funcionar las horas debes pasarlas entre comillas simples o dobles: ("23:00", "11:02") o ('23:00', '11:00') ya que se trata de strings ...

Comment: Con la expresión bien si. Ahora me surge otra duda. Voy a editar la pregunta porque funciona pero si puedes me gustaria que le echases un vistazo.

Comment: Con la expresión bien si. Ahora me surge otra duda. Voy a editar la pregunta porque funciona pero si puedes me gustaria que le echases un vistazo. Al utilizar format() en unos casos tengo que utilizar format("H:i") y en otro format("%H:%I"). Si modifico las i de los primeros casos a I uppercase no funciona. Si les añado los % tampoco. Si los dejo todos igual tampoco.

Comment: De echo, veo que usando en todos los casos format('H:i'), funciona correctamente en los dos de mas arriba, pero en el tercero, exactamente igual me devuelve un string H:i a menos que le añada el %. Esto es lo que no comprendo ahora

Comment: @JoseL. no comprendo tu última duda, si deseas puedes crear una nueva publicación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `strtotime()` para hacer la resta.

La función convierte una cadena de texto en una marca de tiempo UNIX (la cantidad de segundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970 00:00:00 GMT). Luego restas las dos horas y lo divides por 3600 segundos que contiene una hora.

```
function validarHoras($hora1, $hora2){
    try{
        $horaInicial = strtotime($hora1);
        $horaFinal = strtotime($hora2);
        $resultado = ($horaFinal - $horaInicial)/3600;
        return $resultado;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Formato incorrecto";
    }
}

    $diferencia = validarHoras('15:00','11:00');    
    $mensaje = "LA HORA RESTADA ES ".$diferencia." HORAS";
    echo $mensaje;
    //$diferencia devuelve -4
```

Mas info sobre la función [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]