# No consigo entender una expresión regular php

Tags: php, regex

He utilizado la siguiente expresion regular en php para validar una hora en formato hh:mm 24h pero no la entiendo. Estoy mirando la documentación y de todo pero no encuentro nada que me la aclare. Siempre viene todo por separado y hay caracteres que ni eso.
Agradecería algún link donde venga bien explicado para poder generarlas yo.

```
$expresion = "/^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/";
```

Es que no me cuadra nada. ¿Que es [01]? el [0-9] se que es cualquier número. ¿Y despues |2[0-3]?
No le veo la relación para validar una hora de 00:00 hasta 23:59. Si alguien me da unas pinceladas tal vez acabe haciéndolas yo de una vez.

Comment: deberías ser más honesto y mencionar las fuentes correctas en lugar de mentir... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581622/validar-en-php-2-horas-en-formato-hhmm

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Disculpa que te moleste la pregunta. No he sido deshonesto en ningún momento. Ciertamente he usado esa expresión regular y no la entendía. No he dicho la fuente en ningún momento, solo que he usado la expresion. Creo que lo relevante es la duda en si, y no la fuente de la expresion. Pero vamos, si te quedas más tranquilo, la fuente de la expresión es tuya, lo se, ayudandome con una duda anterior. Mi intencion era aclararme con la expresion, ningún interés tengo en ocultar la fuente, ni gano nada con ello. Abrí esta pregunta aparte para aclararla lo antes posible. Nada más.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te explico esta expresión regular por partes, lo primero y más básico el inicio y cierre de la expresión regular:

**Inicio de la Expresión Regular:** `/^`

**Cierre de la Expresión Regular:** `$/`

Ahora, te explicare esta seccion `([01][0-9]|2[0-3])`, los parentesis `()` son para agrupar una reglas que se colocaran dentro que serian estas: `[01][0-9]|2[0-3]`, aqui hay 2 reglas que se cumplen dependiendo del caso:

**La primera regla:** `[01][0-9]` esto indica que si se coloca como primer número un 0 o un 1, el siguiente puede ser cualquier numero, por ejemplo: `01, 02,..., 19`

**La segunda regla:** `2[0-3]` esto indica que si coloca como primer numero un 2, el siguiente numero solo puede ser 0, 1, 2 o 3, por ejemplo: `20, 21, 22 y 23`

Para terminar esta parte faltaria explicar este simbolo `|` el cual esta en medio de ambas reglas, el cual significa `o` o `or` (en ingles), basicamente se cumple la primera regla `o` la segunda regla

Los 2 puntos solo simbolizan a los `:` del formato de hora que quieres, los que dividen el primer numero y el segundo

Y por ultimo están las siguientes 2 reglas que son fáciles de entender:

**Primer número después del separador(:):** `[0-5]` el numero debe ser 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 o 5

**Segundo número después del separador(:):** `[0-9]` puede ser cualquier número

Comment: `/` es el delimitador, `^` no es el "*inicio de la expresión regular*",  coincide con una posición en el texto, y lo mismo para `$/` que no es el "*cierre de la expresión regular*"

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, podrías editar la respuesta y con esto y asi yo apruebo esa edición

Comment: Las ediciones no son para alterar el significado de una respuesta (incluso cuando podría editar sin la necesidad de que apruebes). `^` y `$` están descriptos en https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions

Comment: Muy bien explicado, me ha quedado claro totalmente.

Comment: De nada @JoseL.